# enable socket auto read after disabling it

Tags: netty

after i have disabled auto read on a channel as part of ServerBootstrap using childOption as listed below, how do I enabled auto-read? Or it cannot be enabled, and I have to manually fire channel.read whenever I want to read from channel?

```
new ServerBootstrap().group(new NioEventLoopGroup(2), new NioEventLoopGroup).
  channel(classOf[NioServerSocketChannel]).
  localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port)).
  childOption(AUTO_READ_CHANNEL_OPTION, false).
  childHandler(channelInitializer).bind()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can enable / disable it on the fly. Just use `channel.config().setAutoRead(true)` to enable it and `channel.config().setAutoRead(false)` to disable it. Also note if you set it to `true` and it was `false` before it will automatically trigger a read during the mode change.